# Getting parent Component via Injector.get() when token can be multiple values

Tags: angular, angular2-injection

What I'm trying to do:

- Multiple different components that make use of a single directive
- when the directive is called, I need to be able to get the parent/host component that the directive is called from.

Plnkr -> http://plnkr.co/edit/Do4qYfDLtarRQQEBphW3?p=preview

In looking at the angular.io documentation, I've found that "Injector" can be used to obtain the parent Component in the constructor

```js
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private hostComponent:Injector){
    el.nativeElement.draggable = 'true';
}
```

In doing so,  I get Injector Object. From what I can tell I am then supposed to use

```js
this.hostComponent.get(INJECTORTOKEN)
```

The issues I'm having difficulty grasping is that, the examples provided in Angular, make the assumption that you know the type of Component to provide in the token. ie:

```js
this.hostComponent.get(Image);
this.hostComponent.get(Box);
```

In the pnkr example, I have two components in my template

```html
<div>
   <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
   <my-image></my-image> <!-- Uses the "My Directive" -->
   <my-box></my-box> <!-- Uses the "My Directive" -->
</div>
```

My questions is, in the "mydirective.ts". how can I leverage the "injector.get()" when I don't know if the parent is an "my-image" or 'my-box' component.

in the sample provided, the directive is triggered "ondrag()". view the Console, for log messages.

Any assistance is gratefully appreciated.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know several ways to do that:

1) Find a parent by its class-interface

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-a-parent-by-its-class-interface

You need the provider's class-interface token like:

```js
export abstract class Parent { }
```

After that you should write an alias provider on `Box` and `Image` component

**box.ts**

```js
providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => Box) }]
```

**image.ts**

```js
providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => Image) }]
```

then use it in your directive as shown below

**myDirective.ts**

```js
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(@Optional() private parent: Parent){}

  @HostListener('dragstart',['$event']) ondragstart(event){
    switch(this.parent.constructor) {
     case Box:
      console.log('This is Box');
      break;
     case Image:
      console.log('This is Image');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QcS5x9Lov9cAL0BqQxYU?p=preview)**

2) Inject all your parents as `Optional` token

**myDirective.ts**

```js
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(
    @Optional() private image: Image, 
    @Optional() private box: Box){}

    @HostListener('dragstart',['$event']) ondragstart(event){
      if(this.box) {
        console.log('This is Box');
      }
      if(this.image) {
        console.log('This is Image');
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GuIIv9avKdBNSuISmu6O?p=preview)** for this case

3) Use `Injector` like

```js
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private injector: Injector){}

  @HostListener('dragstart',['$event']) ondragstart(event){
    const boxComp = this.injector.get(Box, 0);
    const imageComp = this.injector.get(Image, 0);

    if(boxComp) {
      console.log('This is Box');
    }
    if(imageComp) {
      console.log('This is Image');
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHztevz11wOZXnaf4mkw?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you so much. this addressed the issue and offers me a path forward on a number of different issues as well. Merci Beaucoup!